# exact solution to this differential equation in mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions

I am trying to solve this differential equation. 
$-\phi_{xx}+\sin\phi=\varepsilon\sin\phi\sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=+\infty}\delta\left(x-n a\right)$

This equation is equivalent to the equation $-\phi_{xx}+\sin\phi=0$ supplemented by the boundary conditions
$\\ \phi\left(x-na=-0\right)=\phi\left(x-na=+0\right)$,
$\phi_{x}\left(x-na=-0\right)-\phi_{x}\left(x-na=+0\right)=\varepsilon\sin\phi\left(x-na=0\right)$,

How do I plug in these boundary conditions to get the expected solution 
$\cos\phi=2k^{2}\text{sn}^{2}\left(x-\frac{a}{2},k\right)-1$ where $\text{sn }$ is the Jacobi elliptic sine with modulus $k$ determined by the transcedental equation $\text{sn }^{2}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)=\frac{4+\varepsilon^{2}-\left[\left(4+\varepsilon^{2}\right)^{2}-16k^{2}\varepsilon^{2}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2k^{2}\varepsilon^{2}}$

Comment: What was unclear in the documentation about boundary conditions?

Comment: @JimBaldwin thanks for the question. How does one put boundary conditions with the limits +0 and -0 as written in the question ?

Comment: Sorry. I was being too subtle. What effort (such as code) have you done. It would be helpful to include that in your question.

Comment: As a reminder, *Mathematica* is using the parameter convention, while your notation is using the modulus convention for Jacobi elliptic functions. (See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108659) for more details.)